# Calculating daily sunlight hours on the North side of a hill with Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I recently bought a house that sits on the North side of a hill.  The owners say that for a couple of days out of the year the sun never rises over the hill.  It got me thinking of using Wolfram Alpha to compute the maximum altitude of the sun throughout the year, and then the duration that the sun is visible in the sky.

Let's assume the from the house the top of the hill is 30 deg.  On the winter solstice (approx 2020-12-20) [the maximum altitude is 25.89 deg](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sun%20maximum%20altitude%20on%202020-12-20%20in%2011231%20); **thus the house will not get sunlight that day.**

- How can I compute the duration that the sun is above 30 deg for a single day?
- How do I do this for a range of dates?  And graph them for the year?

I can get the angle of the sun and solar noon for a zipcode (I'm using 11231) with `Solar noon in 11231 on 2020-10-01`, but I'm unsure how to proceed further.